# Using a RamDrive on 18.04.01 LTS with HandBrake

Tags: 18.04, ram-usage

I want to utilize some of my very much underused RAM to create a RAM drive so that some software that's heavy on the system can get a little help from using that RAM.

I am specifically wanting to run **Handbrake**, preferably with the GUI.  I have the relevant software and information on how to create the actual RAM drive, so i don't need help there, but I wanted to know if

1. can I set up Handbrake so that it favors the RAM drive over a temporary file directory when doing some calculations what may help with improvement, and if not...
2. is it possible to install my Handbrake somewhere specific (like on the actual RAM drive so that it would automatically just use it; I've noticed that Ubuntu never asks for a installation location, it just puts what it wants where it wants and we have little choice in the matter).
3. But I'd also like to know the answer to the "can I install anything on RAM drive, or can it only be used with things that have settings allowing you to force it to use the ram drive as its temp working drive, or is all software just installed where it is and that isn't changeable (from a layman point of view).

Handbrake does make my processor work very hard and it gets very warm, which was another reason that was chosen as the random example before.

Comment: No need. Linux uses RAM efficiently to cache both software and disk activity. Adding RAM space will not help you in this respect.

Comment: Even if it were possible to install Handbrake on a ramdisk, it would not survive a reboot.

Comment: @vanadium i noticed a large difference when i used an SSD for the processing, i just don't want to kill it, i was looking at using ramdrive alternative really and ramdrive was recommended to me, but thanks for your content, I'll certainly look into that.

Comment: @PerlDuck that's not an issue, it takes but 2 seconds to install stuff on the ramdrive (on the few pieces of software it works for me, i just install things as i need them. They would never be for a permanent feature, just to be usable every now and then when it would be helpful.  Thank you though :-)

Comment: What kind of processing? If a HDD is a bottleneck for reencoding video, you have a crappy hard drive.

Comment: If "tear and wear" of your SSD is the issue, then you should clarify this in your question. Now, the question appears as if you are looking for improved performance. Your comment suggests you are looking for reduced tear of your SSD. Having your system tmp files setup in RAM may already make a difference. Things written in a RAM disk indeed will never make it to the SSD.

Comment: @vanadium my question was asking about installing a specific program directly to, or to work on, a RamDrive.  The reason i want to isn't relevant to the question, i just mentioned a random one (of many), i only include handbrake in that list because i know using it on an ssd does make a big difference in performance, but i like to keep my sdds looking after the OS and not processing stuffs.  I mentioned nothing about a bottleneck, because there isn't one.  I just picked handbrake because the computer is already using a lot of number crunching processing power, so it's one I'd to try in ram.

Comment: There's no point in installing software to a RAM drive. The software is loaded into memory **before** you execute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, applications on Linux use the dedicated tmp directories, /tmp or /var/tmp, for their temporary files. `/tmp` allegedly is for quick short term use, whereas `/var/tmp`should persist between boots. If your aim is to reduce tear and wear of an SSD disk, then moving /tmp to RAM will eliminate SSD disk activity when applications write to these temporary directories.

You can move `/tmp` to RAM adding this line to your `/etc/fstab`:

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime 0       0
```

The memory used by a tmpfs file system grows ans shrinks according to the needs. If memory is lacking, swap is used. By default, Ubuntu already uses tmpfs by default for directories like `/run`, `/dev/shm` and others.

Obviously, this is a generic answer. It will help you also for Handbrake provided that application also uses /tmp for its temporary files.

Comment: Yet answers my questions perfectly.  Thank you.  I'll try just changing my tmp dir into a ram slot as you suggest.  From that i will at least know if the ramdrive would work on a much not regular setting (and i gather your implication about moving the/tmp i should know if it things are affected positively.  If i may ask 1 extra question here, can a ramdrive be too big?  I have 64GiBs of ram, but i notice from logs that i averagely use less than a quarter.  So if i was to make it 50GiGs would that help me keep more IO processing off the main drive, or is that overkill? (Your opinion please)

Comment: And you would risk more disk IO, as less RAM is available for dynamic caching as determined by the OS...

Comment: You do not need to specify a size: the tempfs is sized dynamically. You can, however, limit its max size with an option. In the unlikely event that at some point you require very much space, swap (thus your SSD) will be used. Yet, with your 64 GB of RAM, that will typically never happen.

Answer (score 3):

Handbrake is a video conversion tool. Video conversion tools tends to be CPU/GPU-heavy, not IO-heavy.

Encoding on CPU, I typically get 25-100 frames per second. If you have a 50Mb/s 24fps film, this means that you have to ingest 200Mb/s, or 25MB/s. This is *sequential* read from a file, which is the *easiest and most predictable* IO. Even a spinning 5400RPM cheap laptop hard drive will have zero problems keeping up with that.

Even if you quadruple your encoding ratio, to 400fps, it's only 100MB/s. That's within reach of 7200rpm hard drives, and **trivial** for SSDs. You'll probably see zero improvement on encoding speeds by using RAM to cache data for video conversion, unless you have very specialized hardware for video encoding. In that case, the way to go is probably fast SSDs, which can easily handle gigabytes per second.

RAM only makes sense if disk IO is your bottleneck. To optimize, you should *first* identify the actual bottleneck, and then figure out what you can do to work around that bottleneck.

Additionally, dedicating RAM for a RAM drive may make things slower. Linux is pretty good at caching stuff in unused RAM. However, if you force it to cache some things by using a dedicated RAM drive, you risk that things that *could* benefit from being cached won't be cached.

There's certainly some situations in which you want to explicitly cache things in RAM...

1. You have to cache some input for processing, **quickly**. This may for instance be a burst of data from some external sensor, that delivers data for a brief period of time, at a rate that is faster than your disk. In this case, caching it before writing to disk is a good strategy.
2. You have a process, that is IO bound, that needs to store a data set temporarily.
3. You have (small) amounts of data that you don't care about, but you need temporarily. This may for instance be phpsession-files for a webserver.

In many cases, the second example may be replaced by pipes, so that no storage is needed. Storage would only be needed in cases where the complete data set has to be available at once.

In most other cases you will have to read or write the data to disk anyway. If you want to keep the result of a transcode, you have to move it to a disk. If you want to move a video to be transcoded to a RAM drive, you have to read it from disk first, and so forth...

Remember that the OS caches files in RAM by default. Whenever a file is read by the OS, it's cached in RAM. When a file is written, it's cached.

Comment: Try to forget reading handbrake.  The question being asked is about using a ramdrive in lieu of an SSD. I want to know if i would get similar results from a ramdrive than i would on an SSD, and certainly than with a rusty HHD.  My processor already works too hard, and handbrake is I've if the few i want to try to shift to the RamDrive to see about results.

Comment: My question is much less complicated, i just included 1 piece of software's name, but there are few i want to try. So consider it a generic question. I want to run run long term conversions for a while (handbrake was just the first choice). I mainly want to know how to install software so that it runs on the ramdrive.

Comment: The answer is basically the same anyway, unless it's entirely IO-bound. And there's no point in *installing* the software to RAM-disk, as the application is entirely loaded into memory **before** it's executed. It *may* be a point to have the **data set** in RAM in some cases.

Comment: Oh, and just fyi, there is no bottle neck, I'm hoping to have systems in place to prevent that as the computer slowly ages.  In already have a long term place in mind for the Ramdrive, but if i can make one or two other pressures off that hard drives and the system drives.

Comment: Every application has *some* bottleneck. For video encoding it's typically CPU or whatever encoder hardware you're using...

Comment: Just CPU power, my video card is already too busy to help out with hardbrake so it's all processor and CPU.  I'm still interested in if it's possible and how to do it, which was my original questions, everyone got hung up on handbrake when that's not my question, it was just an example.

Comment: Then I would advise asking about optimizing a specific use case. Optimizing is hard, and in general modern operating systems are fairly good at it.